# cassandra: compare timestamp in python

Tags: python, cassandra

I am using [Cassandra Python Driver](http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/getting_started.html), a little confused.

```
res = dbconnection.execute("""select sum(count) from A = a and day >= %s;""", (myday, ));
```

Cluster key `day` is timestamp in Cassandra. what `myday` should be? `epoch in milliseconds`, OR `epoch in seconds`, OR string like `2016-10-26 00:00:00`?
Any performance difference?

Any comments welcomed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [doc page](http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/dates_and_times.html#write-path) that discusses the details of working with time with the Python driver.

You are correct that it can be either a `datetime`, or integer milliseconds from epoch.

Integer input would be marginally more efficient, but you will probably not observe any performance difference, since [query time] >> [parameter encoding].

Answer (score 0):

From the [link you provided](http://datastax.github.io/python-driver/getting_started.html#type-conversions), the python `datetime` is cast to the CQL `timestamp`.  Read more about `datetime` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects).

Comment: But it seems that it also accept epoch in milliseconds.